# Creating new numpy arrays based on condition

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have 2 numpy arrays:

```
aa = np.random.rand(5,5)
bb = np.random.rand(5,5)
```

How can I create a new array which has a value of 1 when both aa and bb exceed 0.5?

Comment: What do you mean when both aa and bb exceed 0, aa and bb are matrices containing values with range between [0-1]

Comment: sorry, updated question. Both should exceed 0.5

Comment: What happens when they are below 0.5? Is the corresponding value 0?

Comment: yes, if below 0.5, then assigned value should be 0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With focus on performance and using two methods few aproaches could be added. One method would be to get the boolean array of valid ones and converting to `int` datatype with [`.astype() method`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html). Another way could involve using [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) that lets us select between `0` and `1` based on the same boolean array. Thus, essentially we would have two methods, one that harnesses efficient datatype conversion and another that uses selection criteria. Now, the boolean array could be obtained in two ways - One using simple comparison and another using [`np.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html). So, with two ways to get the boolean array and two methods to convert the boolean array to `int` array, we would end up with four implementations as listed below -

```
out1 = ((aa>0.5) & (bb>0.5)).astype(int)
out2 = np.logical_and(aa>0.5, bb>0.5).astype(int)
out3 = np.where((aa>0.5) & (bb>0.5),1,0)
out4 = np.where(np.logical_and(aa>0.5, bb>0.5), 1, 0)
```

You can play around with the datatypes to use less precision types, which shouldn't hurt as we are setting the values to `0` and `1` anyway. The benefit should be noticeable speedup as it leverages memory efficiency. We could use [`int8`, `uint8`, `np.int8`, `np.uint8` types](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html). Thus, the variants of the earlier listed  approaches using the new `int` datatypes would be -

```
out5 = ((aa>0.5) & (bb>0.5)).astype('int8')
out6 = np.logical_and(aa>0.5, bb>0.5).astype('int8')
out7 = ((aa>0.5) & (bb>0.5)).astype('uint8')
out8 = np.logical_and(aa>0.5, bb>0.5).astype('uint8')

out9 = ((aa>0.5) & (bb>0.5)).astype(np.int8)
out10 = np.logical_and(aa>0.5, bb>0.5).astype(np.int8)
out11 = ((aa>0.5) & (bb>0.5)).astype(np.uint8)
out12 = np.logical_and(aa>0.5, bb>0.5).astype(np.uint8)
```

Runtime test (as we are focusing on performance with this post) -

```
In [17]: # Input arrays
    ...: aa = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
    ...: bb = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
    ...: 

In [18]: %timeit ((aa>0.5) & (bb>0.5)).astype(int)
    ...: %timeit np.logical_and(aa>0.5, bb>0.5).astype(int)
    ...: %timeit np.where((aa>0.5) & (bb>0.5),1,0)
    ...: %timeit np.where(np.logical_and(aa>0.5, bb>0.5), 1, 0)
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 9.13 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 9.16 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit ((aa>0.5) & (bb>0.5)).astype('int8')
    ...: %timeit np.logical_and(aa>0.5, bb>0.5).astype('int8')
    ...: %timeit ((aa>0.5) & (bb>0.5)).astype('uint8')
    ...: %timeit np.logical_and(aa>0.5, bb>0.5).astype('uint8')
    ...: 
    ...: %timeit ((aa>0.5) & (bb>0.5)).astype(np.int8)
    ...: %timeit np.logical_and(aa>0.5, bb>0.5).astype(np.int8)
    ...: %timeit ((aa>0.5) & (bb>0.5)).astype(np.uint8)
    ...: %timeit np.logical_and(aa>0.5, bb>0.5).astype(np.uint8)
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.6 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.61 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.63 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.63 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.62 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.62 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.62 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.61 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit 1 * ((aa > 0.5) & (bb > 0.5)) #@BPL's vectorized soln
100 loops, best of 3: 10.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: thanks @Divakar, this is a very clear and great answer

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, if i create a mask array of size 100 x 100 using the method you specified, how would i mask it on lets say an array "arr "which is of  100 x 100  to filter values where true gives me actual value in array "arr" for that location and false gives me -1

Comment: @ATHER Think you want `np.where(mask,arr,-1)`.

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
import numpy as np

aa = np.random.rand(5, 5)
bb = np.random.rand(5, 5)

print aa
print bb

cc = 1 * ((aa > 0.5) & (bb > 0.5))
print cc
```

Answer (score -3):

when element of aa and bb at index i is exceed than 0.5 then new array 
have 1 at index i

```
aa = np.random.rand(5,5)
bb = np.random.rand(5,5)
new_arr = []
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if aa[i] >0.5 and bb[i]>0.5:
              new_arr[i] = 1
        else:
              new_arr[i] = "any Value You want
```

Comment: Using Numpy without using ufuncs (especially if they exist) is never the answer.

Comment: You can get real performance troubles working with numpy this way.

Comment: The purpose of `numpy` is to exploit vectorization.  This is clearly not the best way to use `numpy` or you've written this question without knowing how `numpy` works.