# How to replace all values in a numpy array with zero except one specific value?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D numpy array with 'n' unique values.
I want to produce a binary matrix, where all values are replaced with
'zero' and a value which I specify is assigned as 'one'.

For example, I have an array as follows and I want all instances
of 35 to be assigned 'one':

```
array([[12, 35, 12, 26],
       [35, 35, 12, 26]])
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

what is the most efficient way to do it in Python?

Comment: use numpy.zeros(), but save the indices of your wanted values. After replace one in that indices.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[12, 35, 12, 26], [35, 35, 12, 26]])
(x == 35).astype(int)
```

will give you:

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

The == operator in numpy performs an element-wise comparison, and when converting booleans to ints True is encoded as 1 and False as 0.

Comment: @kmario23 Well, the fastest one would be with `(x == 35).astype()`, but using one of `8-bit` based dtypes - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38988035/. Hence, it would be one of - `(x == 35).astype(np.uint8)` ones.

Comment: @kmario23 And leverage `numexpr` module for large arrays - `import numexpr as ne; ne.evaluate('x==35').astype(np.uint8)` for further speedup. Also, we can just view those - `(x == 35).view(np.uint8)`, etc. if views are okay.

Comment: @Divakar: `numexpr` is indeed the fastest by far; thanks for this nice alternative.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for all your suggestions! Added  comprehensive timings below, including your suggested approaches :)

Answer (score 7):

One more elegant way when compared to all other solutions, would be to just use [`np.isin()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

```
>>> arr
array([[12, 35, 12, 26],
       [35, 35, 12, 26]])

# get the result as binary matrix
>>> np.isin(arr, 35).astype(np.uint8)
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

[`np.isin()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) would return a *boolean mask* with `True` values where the given element (here `35`) is present in the original array, and `False` elsewhere.

---

Another variant would be to cast the boolean result using [`np.asarray()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html#numpy.asarray) with data type [`np.uint8`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html) for better speed:

```
In [18]: np.asarray(np.isin(x, 35), dtype=np.uint8)
Out[18]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

---

#### Benchmarking

By explicitly casting the boolean result to [`uint8`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html), we can gain more than **3x better performance**. (Thanks to [@Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) for pointing this out!) See timings below:

```
# setup (large) input array
In [3]: x = np.arange(25000000)
In [4]: x[0] = 35
In [5]: x[1000000] = 35
In [6]: x[2000000] = 35
In [7]: x[-1] = 35
In [8]: x = x.reshape((5000, 5000))

# timings
In [20]: %timeit np.where(x==35, 1, 0)
427 ms ± 25.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [21]: %timeit (x == 35) + 0
450 ms ± 72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [22]: %timeit (x == 35).astype(np.uint8)
126 ms ± 37.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# the fastest choice to go for!    
In [23]: %timeit np.isin(x, 35).astype(np.uint8)
115 ms ± 2.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [24]: %timeit np.asarray(np.isin(x, 35), dtype=np.uint8)
117 ms ± 2.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

If you want a real warhorse, then use [`numexpr`](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html) as in:

```
In [8]: import numexpr as ne

In [9]: %timeit ne.evaluate("x==35").astype(np.uint8)
23 ms ± 2.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

This is ***ca. 20x faster*** than the slowest approach using NumPy based computations.

---

Finally, if *views* are okay, we can get such crazy speedups using NumPy approaches itself.

```
In [13]: %timeit (x == 35).view(np.uint8)
20.1 ms ± 93.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [15]: %timeit np.isin(x, 35).view(np.uint8)
30.2 ms ± 1.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

(Again, thanks to [@Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) for mentioning [these super nice tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308240/how-to-replace-all-values-in-a-numpy-array-with-zero-except-one-specific-value/48308307?noredirect=1#comment83617229_48308307)!)

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[12, 35, 12, 26], [35, 35, 12, 26]])
(x == 35) + 0
```

> array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
>          [1, 1, 0, 0]])

Comment: Oh, very clever. I went ahead an did a minor edit. The thought is good, however, I think that `boolean_array + 0` is not the most efficient way to convert data-types.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to use `np.where`; this solution is slower than [@yuji's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48308307/1534017) (see timings below) but it is more flexible if you want to do anything else but putting in zeroes and ones (see example below).

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[12, 35, 12, 26], [35, 35, 12, 26]])
np.where(x==35, 1, 0)
```

which yields

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

One can read it like *where x is equal to 35 put in a 1, everywhere else insert a 0*.

As written, you now have great flexibility, you can e.g. also do the following:

```
np.where(x==35, np.sqrt(x), x - 3)

array([[  9.        ,   5.91607978,   9.        ,  23.        ],
       [  5.91607978,   5.91607978,   9.        ,  23.        ]])
```

So everywhere, where `x` is equal to `35`, you get the square root and from all other values you subtract `3`.

Timings:

```
%timeit np.where(x==35, 1, 0)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.85 µs per loop

%timeit (x == 35).astype(int)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.23 µs per loop

%timeit np.isin(x, 35).astype(int)
10000 loops, best of 3: 18.7 µs per loop

%timeit (x == 35) + 0
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.85 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

If your array is a numpy array then you can use the '==' operator on your array to return a boolean array. Then use the astype feature to turn it to zeros and ones.

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.array([[12, 35, 12, 26],
                     [35, 35, 12, 26]])

indexed = (my_array == 35).astype(int)

print indexed
```

Answer (score 2):

I like [@yuji approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48308307/1887559). Very elegant!

Just for a sake of diversity here is another answer with a lot of labor....

```
>>> from numpy import np
>>> x = np.array([[12, 35, 12, 26],[35, 35, 12, 26]])
>>> x
array([[12, 35, 12, 26],
       [35, 35, 12, 26]])
>>> y=np.zeros(x.shape)
>>> y[np.where(x==35)] = np.ones(len(np.where(x==35)[0]))
>>> y
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
>>>
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree and edit my answer, but often works well